# Send as another user / email address in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

In my setup there exist user1, ..., userN@example.com. Mail for example.com is handled by Exchange 2010 and all the users user Outlook 2010. There also exists a Standard Distribution list named office@example.com. Is it possible to have some of the users being able to send email with office@example.com as the sender address? Can the sender's GECOS be different too when this happens so that the recipient sees "Offices of Example.com" instead of "User Name X"?

Sometimes the secretaries need to send stuff as "the office" and not as theirselves ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GrantSendOnBehalfTo Paramenter so that a particular user can send on behalf that distribution list

For more info you can read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124955.aspx)
and here is a simple [tutorial](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-grant-send-behalf-permissions-distribution-group) that explains the whole process